# Solr synonym.txt adding at elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I have already a working synonym.txt in solr. Now I want to add that same txt file at elasticsearch. What can I do for it? At solr it was easy, I just kept that file in the system. At elasticsearch I added this and also run some command, but it is not working.

```
PUT /test_index
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "synonym": {
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "filter": [ "synonym" ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "synonym": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms_path": "analysis/synonym.txt"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What's wrong? Do I need to index it again or do I need to map this with any field? My search result depends on multiple fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you have applied your `synonym` on your existing fields in your ES mapping, you have just provided your index setting, and you need to provide the index mapping to confirm it.

Also adding an analyzer to the existing field is a breaking change and you have to reindex the data again to see the updated tokens.

You must use [Analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) to see the updated tokens on your index, Also please cross-check if you have added the `synonym.txt` properly and there was no error while creating the index setting with this file.